# how to access and push child array of objects into parent array

Tags: arrays, angular

I am trying to push a child array to a parent array and check child array values, how can I a accomplish this or the best way to accomplish this ?

**interface**

```
export interface IErsaApps {
        app_id: number;
        app_type_id: number;
        app_name: string;
        app_roles: string;
        app_sort_id?: number;
        selectedApp: boolean;
        seletedAppRoleID?: number;
        roles: Array<IErsaAppRoles>;
}
export interface IErsaAppRoles {
    app_role_id: number;
    app_role_app_id: number;
    app_role_name: string;
    app_role_sort_id?: number;   
}
export interface IErsaPreviewApp {
    app_type_id: number;
    apps: Array<IErsaApps>;
}
```

**TS**(I can push to the array the first time, however, need to push to child array after that)

```
   selectedObject: IErsaApps; 
      iErsaDefaultApps: IErsaApps[] =[]; 
      iErsaPrevSelectedApps: IErsaPreviewApp[] = [];
    toggleSelectedApp(event: any, rowIndexValue: any)
        { 

         this.selectedObject = this.iErsaAppList .find(x => x.app_id == event.srcElement.value);

    //This work        
    this.iErsaPrevSelectedApps.splice(0, 0, { "app_type_id": this.selectedObject.app_type_id, "apps": [this.selectedObject] });

    //trying to push just the child, how do I do that?              
                        this.iErsaPrevSelectedApps.splice(1, 0, { "apps": [this.selectedObject] });


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to push an object into the `apps` (child) `Array`, you can do it this way:

```
this.iErsaPrevSelectedApps[1].apps.splice(0, 0, this.selectedObject);
```

**Notes:**

Using index 1 as per your example : `this.iErsaPrevSelectedApps[1]`

Inserting object at index 0 here: `splice(0, 0, this.selectedObject);`, but you can adjust that as per your requirement.